# How to setup Postman to handle APIs from remote server

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, ssh, postman

I have my django server running in a ssh client (ubuntu) but I want to test the api's in the local window machine. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Use your web app's  url / IP address  in post man, and use the authentication required.  If your django app is not hosted, run python manage.py 0.0.0.0:8000  , and use the IP in the local system

Comment: Can you please elaborate, it is my first time doing this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If your web application is hosted  ( have domain name like
> http://www.stackoverflow.com) use the url in your postman.

If your webapp not yet deployed in some webserver ( apacahe, nginx+gunicorn,  etc)

run the django application publicly in the server IP as follows

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  // make sure port 8000 is open or use an open port.
```

Also find the IP address of your ubuntu using the following command ( in the shell)

```
 ifconfig
```

Use the ip-address you got in the postman (windows)

```
eg: if the IP address got is 90.101.111.25, 
API endpoint: api/user/
method : POST
```

In postman client

```
use the url: 90.101.111.25/api/user/
select method : POST
Next you need to provide the Authorization ( to make sure only guanine users access your API).
```

> Choose Authorization tab in postman, and select the Authorization (
> Digest Auth, Basic, Token) your web app supports.

If you go with Token Authentication, find the the token for the (one of the )user created, and use it in postman.

```
Select Headers and add the following
key: Authorization
value: Token:<space>the-token-generated-by-django-in-the-db
```

Check the following to implement token based authentication in django( django-rest).

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

Comment: Should you put the port number on the url like this? http://90.101.111.25:8000/api/user/

Comment: yes, probably with a ending  '/'.   http://90.101.111.25:8000/api/user//